# GitHub Pull Request badges

Tags: github, markdown, pull-request

Does anyone have an example of adding the status of a pull request to a markdown doc? I am trying to create a readme with a list of PRs, and I want a badge next to each PR with the status of that PR, merged, opened, closed. I haven't been able to find any docs on doing this, but I can't imagine I am the first one to want this feature.

Answer (score 1):

On the Github wiki, issues and other markdown area of your repository, you can link PRs. Hoovering the mouse above the link shows its status. I do not see any other automatic way of showing these information

Answer (score 0):

Github has no built-in way to do this. Github only provides a badge for action status. But You have to do this via a third party.
You can find plenty of examples on this nice page:
https://naereen.github.io/badges/